# Подскажите какой 3Dредактор экспортирует модели форматируя индексы вершин в triangle_strip?

Tags: opengl, 3d, шейдеры

Работаю с openGL и geometry_shader. У геометрического шейдера выходные данные могут быть только трех видов(points, line_strip, triangle_strip). Мне нужен третий вариант. Проблема в том, что мне нужно отрисовывать сферу(650 вершин и 1200 треугольников) по заданным координатам, но все известные мне редакторы экспортируют модели в виде списка вершин и списка треугольников(формат triangles в openGL). А вручную переделывать 1200 треугольников очень сложно.

Подскажите в каких редакторах можно настраивать выходные параметры моделей, чтобы сделать triangle_strip. А если кто-то знает алгоритм форматирования из обычных треугольников в непрерывную полосу triangle_strip или ссылку на него будет вообще замечательно.